# Soundcloud Stratus - Dynamically Add Without Clicking

Tags: jquery, soundcloud, audio-player, soundcloud-stratus

The Soundclous Stratus 2 JQuery music player has a function that allows you to click a properly tagged (class=stratus) link on the page and add it to the player's playlist on the fly.

> Dynamically Add Tracks
>   You can now add tracks to Stratus right from your page. Simply give a SoundCloud track link the class of stratus and the player will do the rest. This works great for the discography section of your site.

http://www.degrade.la

Click on the text that says touch sensitive in blue to see it in action.

Is there a way to make the player add the track to the playlist on the fly without the user having to click the link?

Ultimately, the goal would be to automatically add new songs to the SC playlist simply by linking them on the page and properly classing them, rather than manually adding them to a running SC set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $.each($('.stratus'), function() {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've started using Fullwidth Audio Player instead but I appreciate you taking the time to help.